# Elixir map check if not empty and key exists

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to figure out a way to check if the params hash in a Phoenix app (using Elixir) has a particular key or not.

In the below changeset function in a model, the params is defaulted to :empty.

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
```

I need to figure out if a key named :username exists in the hash.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just a small terminology thing, params is a map and not a hash. This is relevant when knowing where to look in the documentation.

For a map there is [has_key?/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.9.1/Map.html#has_key?/2) which returns `true` or `false`.

```
Map.has_key?(params, :name)
```

Since you are using an Ecto changeset then you can also use [Ecto.Changeset.get_change/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_change/3).

```
get_change(changeset, key, default \\ nil)
```

This returns `default` if `key` is not set. Please note that if `key` is set to `nil` then `nil` will still be returned. If `nil` is a permitted value for your change then you may want to set a different default parameter.

Answer (score 11):

Gazeler's answer is obviously really good. I would only add pattern matching to the mix, as it seems to me, that's the clearest solution, that works not only with phoenix, but with any map anywhere in Elixir.

```
# head-only declaration for default params
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty)

def changeset(model, %{"username" => _} = params) do
  # username field is in params
end

def changeset(model, params) do
  # username is not in params
end
```

Comment: Are you sure is it correct?
map = %{"username" => "Name", "ONE_MORE_KEY" => "VALUE"}
changeset(map)
-----
# username is not in params

Comment: @Puzirki It may looks conter intuitive at first look but any map with the key "username" will match the pattern `%{"username" => _}`. You can test it in the `iex` console by writing `%{"username" => val} = %{"x" => 0, "y" => 1, "username" => 10}`.